# Elements inside custom HTML tag aren't initialised in constructor

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-1.7

I need to access elements inside a custom tag I created `<multi-nav>`. 
The problem is that the constructor isn't called after initializing these elements (which is expected). In this example I can't access the form tag manifested in the object `formTag`.

MultiNav.js

```
class MultiNav extends HTMLElement { 
    get formTag() { 
        return this.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
    }

    get selectTag() {
        return this.formTag.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
    }

    constructor () {
        super();
        this.formTag.addEventListener('submit', function(evt) {
            evt.preventDefault(); // to avoid error, by stopping form from submitting
            console.log("submitting ...");  // doesn’t log because formTag isn’t retrieved
             this.formTag.submit();
        }); 
    }
}


window.customElements.define('multi-nav', MultiNav);
```

The problem is that the error is thrown after calling `addEventListener`, browser says: 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined`

While in the HTML file, (working only on google chrome)

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
 $('input[name=toggle]').change(function(){
    $('#myform').submit();
});
});
</script>

<script language="javascript1.7" src="/js/MultiNav.js">

</script>
<multi-nav>
<form id='myform' action="/action_page.php" method="POST"> 
    <div>
        <label><input type="radio" name="toggle" value="20"><span>$20</span></label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="toggle" value="50"><span>$50</span></label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="toggle" value="100"><span>$100</span></label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="toggle" value="500"><span>$500</span></label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="toggle" value="1000"><span>$1000</span></label>
    </div>
    <select name="stuff" form="myform" title="category" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="category"><button selected disabled>Category<button></option>
        <option value="home"><button>Home<button></option>
        <option value="electronics"><button>Electronics<button></option>
        <option value="cars"><button>Cars<button></option>
    </select>
</form>
</multi-nav>
```

It should have something to do with class lifecycle in JavaScript. But I couldn't find the appropriate function

Comment: Looks like a typical case of `this` confusion. Replace `function(evt)` with arrow syntax to `evt =>` in order to keep same `this`. Alternatively, apply `.bind(this)` to that callback function (after its closing brace).

Comment: It might be another issue if the first one is solved. But the primary issue is that 'addEventListener' is called on an undefined object. (The object formTag hasn't been yet identified)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three issues and solutions:

- `this.formTag` is not defined because the instance of the custom tag is created before the document is loaded, and so `this.getElementsByTagName("form")[0]` is undefined.
  **Solution:** place `window.customElements.define('multi-nav', MultiNav);` within the `ready` callback function.
- `$('#myform').submit()` will submit the form without the `submit` event being triggered.
  **Solution:** include an invisible submit button in your HTML, and trigger a click on it instead of calling the `submit` method.

  ```
  <input type="submit" id="submitButton" style="display:none">
  ```

  JS:

  ```
  $('#submitButton').click();
  ```
- Within the `addEventListener` callback `this` does not refer to your custom object, but to the element on which you call `addEventListener`.
  **Solution**: replace `this.formTag.submit();` by `this.submit()`.

Comment: I executed it and it worked the way you suggested. Regarding **this**, inside the addEventListener callback, I think is where I need to remove the **formTag** because **this** inside it refers to the form object while the outside **this** refers to the custom object. Also I really like the hidden button trick; it's making me feeling silly I have never thought about it before !